# Pointer to an array of pointers referencing functions, how do I change pointer values and call functions?

Tags: c, function-pointers

```
int *(*(*functions_array)[4](); 
int *function() { /*code */ };
```

I know that with a Pointer referencing a function `int *(*func)();` I can just assign pointer value of a function to func `func = &function;` and then call with `func();`.

What's the closest I could get to this behavior but with addition of arrays ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Especially the mention of "but with addition of arrays" doesn't make it seem like you're trying to solve a pragmatical problem. Perhaps post some more code that showcases what you want to do, and explain why you need to use pointers to arrays of function pointers for that task.

Comment: That declaration is an unreadable mess. What's more, it's ill-formed on account of an unmatched parenthesis (no surprisingly given the mess).

Comment: Do step-by-step `typedef`s and combine them to what you need. That will help you and every other programmer read the code.

Comment: You don't need `&` on the function name; the compiler provides it automatically.

Comment: What's that supposed to be? An array of function pointers, an array of array pointers, an array of function pointers returning array pointers...? Kindly compile the code before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function1(void)
{
  printf("function 1\n");
  return 1;
};

int function2(void)
{
  printf("function 2\n");
  return 2;
};

int(*FunctionPointer)(void);             // a function pointer
int(*ArrayOfFunctionPointers[4])(void);  // an array of 4 function pointers


int main()
{
  FunctionPointer = function1;
  FunctionPointer();                     // will call function1

  FunctionPointer = function2;
  FunctionPointer();                     // will call function2

  ArrayOfFunctionPointers[0] = function1;
  ArrayOfFunctionPointers[1] = function2;

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    ArrayOfFunctionPointers[i]();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
function 1
function 2
function 1
function 2
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing's first, the declaration you show is ill-formed. Not surprisingly, given how hard the declarator syntax in C can be. If you wanted an array of function pointers (something I strongly suspect), then the raw spelling is like this:

```
int *(*functions_array[4])();
```

Not much more readable, but at least syntactically correct. You can now index into it to obtain a function pointer for your use. E.g:

```
functions_array[0] = function; 
functions_array[0](); // Call the function
```

But if you really wanted a pointer to an array (for reasons I can't fathom), the raw declarator is this:

```
int *(*(*functions_array_p)[4])();
```

With the now less appealing indexing to match:

```
(*functions_array_p)[0] = function; 
(*functions_array_p)[0](); // Call the function
```

The parenthesis are required due to the regular precedence of `*` and `[]`.

But the way to make working with it and defining it easier, is by introducing some type aliases. Primarily, for the function type:

```
typedef int* function_type();
```

Now the array declaration takes this far more readable form:

```
function_type* functions_array[4];
```

The asterisk in plain sight is inline with the generally good practice of not hiding away pointer semantics.

And for a pointer to an array:

```
function_type* (*functions_array)[4];
```

The declarator is still fairly regular looking.

---

<sub>1. As an aside, an empty parameter list in a C function declaration does not mean the function takes no arguments. It's an obsolescent feature providing a function with no prototype. The way forward is `(void)`.</sub>

Comment: There is a difference between a pointer to an array and an array of pointers.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - I'm not sure the OP actually *needs* a pointer to an array. I suspect they are operating under the misguided assumption that arrays are pointer, and the whole declarator mess and unfamiliarity with the syntax is adding to their confusion and phrasing of the question. But no matter, It's one step away to add a pointer anyway.